# ionic 2 hot/cold observables

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-observables

Hi I am developing an app, where I have an userService class, that manages user data. Here I create observable like this :

```ts
export class UserService {
  currentUser;
  userObservable;
  userObserver;

  constructor(public http: Http,private db:Database, private platform:Platform) {

this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
  this.userObservable=Observable.create(observer=>{
    this.userObserver=observer;
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.getCurrentUser().then((data)=>{
        this.userObserver.next(this.currentUser);
      });
    },600);

  }).publish();
  this.userObservable.connect();
});
  }

  saveUser(user){
this.db.insertUserToUsers(user).then(()=>{
  this.currentUser=user;
  this.userObserver.next(this.currentUser);
    });
      }

  getCurrentUser(){
return new Promise(resolve=>{
  this.db.getUser().then((data)=>{
    this.currentUser=data;
    resolve(this.currentUser);
  });
});
}
```

Then I subscribe to it at home page and at user page in constructor like this :

```ts
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.userService.getCurrentUser().then((data)=>{
        this.currentUser=data;
      });
      this.userSubscription=this.userService.userObservable.subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.currentUser=data;
      });
```

The problem is, the observable start to emit values, everything is ok but homepage, but it doesn't work on user page, because it isn't subscribed in the moment when the observable starts emitting. Is there any way to fix this problem? If I use observable without `publish()` and `connect()`, it doesn't work either, because of some reason - home page subscription ok, user page subscription ok, but after this, the first subscription(subscription from home page) stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: You should store the user in your service and reference that object.to your components object so is remains the same instance

Comment: U mean like directly reference the currentUser variable from userService in Home page and User page? Like this.userService.currentUser? Or create getter in userService, that will return it

Comment: You should use in your component: this.currentUser = this.userService.currentUser.